# customize x-axis interval for a real time line chart in achartengine

Tags: grid, real-time, achartengine, linechart

I have a real-time line chart. For that I use TimeSeries. Now I get new values every second. But I don’t want to get a x-axis line every second. I like to get one every ten seconds.

So maybe, first it would be important to know where the x-axis lines were painted. Is it `xymultipleseriesdataset.addSereies(timeSeries)`? So maybe I can create a loop that add every 10 second a new title for the x-Axis... or am I totally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, you are asking for a way to control which labels are shown on the x-axis.

To do that, you may use the `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.addXTextLabel(timeInMillis, "requiredlabel")`.

<del>This will cause the automatic generation of labels to stop and</del> you can then have complete control on which labels are shown and which are not.

Edit:

Seems like I was wrong about automatic generation of labels stopping.
Use the method `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.setXLabels(0)` to stop the generation of labels. This method is used to set how many labels should be generated for the x axis. Passing 0 should stop automatic labels to stop altogether.

Comment: ehm correct me if I'm wrong. but I thought text Label is only for the text and not for the lines. or is there trick for use this command

Comment: ahh greate it works. Sorry I was wrong. Now I have the Labels I need, but the old lables are still there. So the automatic generation of lables do not stop. is there a way to stop it? I tried mRenderer.clearXTextLabels(); but it does not work